# Error from down-grading Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, downgrade

I'm getting this error, which I have researched about it but the things that I researched and tried didn't work. I got this error from down grading unity 5.4 to unity 5.3 (had some issues please don't comment about it)

I tried double clicking it but it wouldn't show me whats causing the problem. Anyway, this is the error, could anyone help me with this:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEngine.UI.Graphic.OnRebuildRequested () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Graphic.cs:480)
UnityEngine.UI.GraphicRebuildTracker.OnRebuildRequested () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/GraphicRebuildTracker.cs:33)
UnityEngine.CanvasRenderer.RequestRefresh () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/modules/UI/CanvasRendererBindings.gen.cs:314)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try the usual deleting all regeneratable data from the project folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like **Maxim Kamalov** said, do this:

Copy **Assets** and **ProjectSettings** folders to new project folder of your choice like "/MyProject_5.3".

Open Unity3D 5.3 and choose to open existing project, and choose **"/MyProject_5.3"** which should contain only Assets and ProjectSettings folders.

Then Unity3D editor will reimport all things that need to be imported and will do some other stuff (creaitng Temp and Library folders with content).

That should work for you, if not - let us know.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but i'm still getting the same error. :(